# Select the most recent records in exactly a month using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am joining two(2) tables (`users` and `billings`) in Laravel. In the billing table, the user can be billed several times. So, that means the username can appear several times. I want to select the most recent records of the billings based on `created_at` (the date) and pick out the username and the `created_at`.

I have created a select query in Laravel.

```php
$monthlysubscriptionupdate = DB::table("billings")
    ->select("billings.phone", "billings.email", "billings.plan", 
        "billings.created_at", "users.username",
        "users.msisdn", "users.auto_subscription")
    ->join("users", "users.username", "=", "billings.username")
    ->where(['users.package_id' => '1102', 'users.auto_subscription' => 0])
    ->get();
```

In the billing table, the user can be billed several times. So, that means the username can appear several times. I want to select the most recent records of the billings based on `created_at` (the date) and pick out the username and the `created_at` for the username in precisely a month between the current date and `created_at`. Please note that each username appears several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this for get the data of the current month:

```
$currentMonth = date('m');
$monthlysubscriptionupdate =  DB::table("billings")
        ->select("billings.phone","billings.email","billings.plan","billings.created_at","users.username", "users.msisdn", "users.auto_subscription")
       ->join("users","users.username","=","billings.username")
       ->where(['users.package_id'=>'1102', 'users.auto_subscription'=>0])
      ->whereRaw('MONTH(billings.created_at) = ?',[$currentMonth])
       ->orderBy("billings.created_at", "desc")
       ->get();
```

Or if you want to get the last 30 days try this:

```
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(30);
DB::table("billings")
        ->select("billings.phone","billings.email","billings.plan","billings.created_at","users.username", "users.msisdn", "users.auto_subscription")
       ->join("users","users.username","=","billings.username")
       ->where(['users.package_id'=>'1102', 'users.auto_subscription'=>0])
       ->where('billings.created_at', '>=',$date)
       ->orderBy("billings.created_at", "desc")
       ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use whereDate + orderBy as Daniel Luna said. Example of whereDate

```
$q->whereDate('created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'));
```

Anyway, If you are using this type of DB structure in where you need to deal with complex queries, I extremely recommend you to use Eloquent and an object oriented structure of your project. Like this you will be able to avoid queries as long as a paragraph ^_^ like this one.